# Spark Streaming IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

So using:
 - Spark Structured Streaming (2.1.0)
 - Kafka 0.10.2.0
 - Scala 2.11

I am consuming with the default API from Kafka, so basically:

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option(...)
```

Setting up the options (over SSL) and everything. Then I obvisouly apply a few actions etc and start the stream, etc (it runs properly). However from time to time it throws an exception:

```
17/05/30 11:05:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 23.0 in stage 77.0 (TID 3329, spark-worker-3, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalStateException: This consumer has already been closed.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.ensureNotClosed(KafkaConsumer.java:1611)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1622)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.fetchData(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:177)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any tips why could this be failing?

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18682 fixed it when implementing the batch Kafka source. You should not be able to see it in Spark 2.1.1. If you still see this error in Spark 2.1.1, please create a Spark ticket on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK

Comment: Could you check my other message to the post? THanks in advance

Comment: Hello again, I still get it in 2.2.0. I opened an issue and it was "declined" could you give me a hand? is a bit blocking for me atm: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21453

Comment: I can see it even with 3.0.2. from time to time.
Mostly when retry task which was cached.